# Cannot find Class template in Add New Item

Tags: visual-studio

I'm suddenly missing the empty class template.  I suspect that it is because of uninstalling Resharper.  Is there any way to get it back outside of re-installing?  I tried devenv /installvstemplates but this did not help.

[image]

I think I may be missing something from this folder:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try devenv /setup now that you've done that.

You could create custom templates if that doesn't work, and you absolutely cannot reinstall.  The instructions for that are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247113.aspx

Comment: Thanks for writing, I found under the Web directory another copy of Class.zip which I copied over to IDE/ItemTemplates/CSharp/Code/1033 but after running devenv /installvstemplates and later devenv /setup, I still don't see anything under "Code".  :(

Comment: According to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1.aspx it goes in \CSharp\1033 (without the "Code")

Comment: Do you see it under your \CSharp\1033 folder?  could you post a copy?

Comment: i found it in another computer with vs installed, i ended up copying Class CodeFile and Interface which were all missing from the CSharp\1033\Code file, i then ran installvstemplates and setup and it now works.  thanks for your help
!

Comment: I FOUND IT!  On my VS 2010 Pro install media, it's in cab49 and is named FL_Class_zip_109331_109331_cn_enu.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8, so just rename it to Class.zip